# Am I understanding Inheritance wrong?

Tags: python, python-3.x, inheritance

I'm a bit puzzled by a problem:

```python
class AwinBaseOperator:
    def __init__(self):
        print('parent init')
        self.data = self.get_data(query_url='test')

    def get_data(self, query_url):
        print('parent called with ', repr(query_url))

class AwinTransactionOperator(AwinBaseOperator):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        print('child init')

    def get_data(self):
        print('child called')
        
print(AwinTransactionOperator())
```

I get this error :

```
TypeError: get_data() got an unexpected keyword argument 'query_url'
```

My understanding is that the constructor in `AwinBaseOperator` *should* use the method `get_data(self, query_url)` from `AwinBaseOperator` but instead uses the one in the child-class definition, for which the signature is `get_data(self)`

Is my understanding of inheritance wrong? Shouldn't anything in the parent class definition use the methods from **its own class**? Why doesn't the `self` instance variable change into the parent scope when going through the `super` operator?

Comment: you are overriding the function, get_data function from `AwinTransactionOperator` is [overriding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_overriding) `AwinBaseOperator` class `get_data` function

Comment: **MINIMAL** reproducible example. This question originally contained tons of extraneous detail about AirFlow, which is irrelevant to the problem at hand. I edited it out, only keeping the class and method names.

Comment: @sahasrara62 Obviously, I am overriding it, but I am not calling it directly from the `AwinTransactionOperator, it's the constructor of `AwinBaseOperator` that is the caller. So I guess the question is, why does is `self` operator an instance of `AwinTransactionOperator` even when the `super` operator is called.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not like C or C++ you can't do function X signatures and it'll detect the correct one of the definitions.

When you call `self.get_data` it's calling the `get_data` of the current object, if you inherit from class and you've the same method redefinition but with different arguments it still will overwrite it.

To call the `super` class get_data you can instead of `self.get_data('url')` use `super().get_data('url')`.

(You have `self.get_data` at the subclass if you didn't notice as well)

Comment: I can't use `super().get_data(`url`), as the problem comes from the `get_data` in the `AwinBaseOperator` constructor. What if I instanciate an `AwinBaseOperator` later? how would the `super` act?

Comment: It's coming from the `self.get_data` because you call it with parameter, it should not get parameters.
`super` is just the class you inherit from. You should use `super().get_data(url)` instaed of `self.get_data(url)`.